# multiline view for lists

Tags: list-view, xslt

I have a list that currently looks like this (Excel mockup):

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I tried to be really sneaky and insert `</tr><tr>` in the XSL but SharePoint just strips it out when I save it. (Actually, I used `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</tr><tr>]]></xsl:text>` because otherwise the HTML/XML validator complains about mismatched tags.)

I tried searching for multiline views in Google, etc., but multiline is too noisy and I couldn't find anything useful.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need you XSL to look something like this:

```
<tr>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@Client" /></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@Date1" /></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@Date2" /></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@Date3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@Rep" /></td>
 <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="@Elapsed1-2" /></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@Elapsed3-4" /></td>
</tr>
```